# Display the image in the image view in listview.in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to display my image in the image view to a list view.

```
listItems.add(Login.uname+":"+editText.getText().toString()+"wahii" + iv);
```

iv is my image view.

now the problem is it did not display the image.instead it displays  like
"bitmapdrawable@417dadc0"

is it possible to do ???

Comment: please post your complete code.

Comment: Do you know anything about array adapters?

Comment: @saeed I am starting with array adapters

Comment: So just learn more about them. They are the answer to your question. You need a custom adapter and a Custom object for showing what you want. Concatenating those strings and feed them to the adapter is not the answer!!!

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: ya , for now I solved it. uses a  template xml file for lay out which contains a image view and a list view. and on my button click it will display  this template. but I need more on this to solve. I need to display the images from database in the list view. I am working on it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add images to a listview or you want to add both text and images side by side, the best option one has is to use a custom adapter and setting your own layout for each row. Google or overflow to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve your image from `ImageView` using :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

where image is your `ImageView` and pass this `Bitmap` to wherever required

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of my array adapter for your reference in which I did the same thing ,this is what I think you need

```
public class FamilyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShortProfileBean> {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<ShortProfileBean> data;
        private Context context;

        public FamilyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                List<ShortProfileBean> data) {
            super(context, resource, data);
            inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            //if it's not create convertView yet create new one and consume it
            if(convertView == null){

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.familylistview, null);
                //get new ViewHolder
                holder =new ViewHolder();
                //get all item in ListView item to corresponding fields in our ViewHolder class
                holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRelPic);
                holder.name =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRelName);
                holder.relation =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRelation);
                //set tag of convertView to the holder
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            //if it's exist convertView then consume it
            else {
                holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }  

            loadImageFromAsset(holder.image, data.get(position).picture);
            holder.name.setText(data.get(position).name);
            holder.relation.setText(data.get(position).relation);
            //return ListView item
            return convertView;
        }

        /*
         * To load image from assets folder
         * param im : ImageView 
         * param imageName: Name of your image with extension
         * 
         */
            public void loadImageFromAsset(ImageView im , String imageName){
                // load image
                try {
                    // get input stream
                    InputStream ims = context.getAssets().open(imageName);
                    // load image as Drawable
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
                    // set image to ImageView
                    im.setImageDrawable(d);
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        //ViewHolder class that hold over ListView Item 
        static class ViewHolder{
            ImageView image;
            TextView name;
            TextView relation;
        }
    }
```